# Strip out variable spaces and replace with comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some data in text format which reads like this:

```
  11-Jun-97 Jason Smith                              Pizza                 175 Cafe   Australia                                          Aaron & James
  12-Jul-97 Alan Davidson                     Fried Chicken                   183 Outdoors      New Zealand                   Anthony
```

In short there is a date, person's name, food, ID, location, country and source. This is consistent throughout but the spacing between the items is variable.

I would like to replace the spaces with a comma so I can view in a spreadsheet. Thanks

Comment: This is going to be difficult/impossible because we don't know whether a space is part of the entry (e.g. the space in `New Zealand`), or if the space(s) are separators.  I would recommend that you fix this in the source of your data.  Whence is the above data?

Comment: Can this be done for anything greater than a single space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem you face is that we don't know what a single space means here.  In the case of the country `New Zealand`, the space is part of the data itself which you want to keep.  In the case of the many spaces separating most of the columns, they have no real meaning, and you want to replace them with something else.

That being said, you should be able to target groups of two or more spaces.

First trim away whitespace occurring at the beginning/end of each line:

```
Find:    ^[ ]+(.*\S+)[ ]+$
Replace: $1
```

Then replace the internal multi spaces with comma, followed by a single space:

```
Find:    [ ]{2,}
Replace: ,[ ]        <-- one space after the comma
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This kinda worked but it also stripped the line feed at the end of the line. So all lines got appended to each other.

Comment: @ratsstack I botched the order of replacements.  Undo what you tried, and try my updated answer.  If you strip whitespace first, then it should work.  I can't test my answer right now, because I don't have Notepad++ on this machine.

Comment: @ratsstack For future reference, most of the time when you export data like yours, you would have the chance to put quotes around each field.  Then, `New Zealand` would appear as `"New Zealand"`, and we would be able to tell apart spaces you want from spaces you don't want.  Glad to help you in any case.